# Is it possible to json_encode the value undefined in php?

Tags: javascript, php, json, undefined, morris.js

I am trying to json encode a variable to have the value of `undefined`, as in the javascript keyword `undefined`. I tried to google this, but the only results that show up are about people getting errors in their php script that the actual function `json_encode` is undefined. Is there a way to do undefined? To encode the value `NULL` it is simply `null` without quotes. Using `"undefined"` in php treats it as a string, and of course `undefined` doesn't work since php thinks that is a constant.

I tried this in javascript:

```
JSON.stringify([undefined,null]);
```

but it returned

```
[null,null]
```

**So is it even possible to encode the value `undefined`?**

The reason I am asking is that I am using the morris.js charting library, and it handles `null` values differently than `undefined` values when your line chart is  missing data points, and I want them to be handled as `undefined`. I realize I could loop thru my `JSON` object and convert all `null`s to `undefined`s, but I want to know if it is even possible to encode `undefined`.

In general, there are several situations where `undefined` may be handled differently than `null` so this would be applicable to all of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. JSON does not support a value of `undefined`. The closest relatives would be `null` or `false`. According to [the specification](http://www.json.org), valid JSON values are: string, number, object, array, `true`, `false`, and `null`.

Moreover, how would you check for its existence in an object?<sup>1</sup>

```
var a = {"key1":undefined,"key2":"value2"};
var b = {"key2":"value2"};
if(typeof(a.key1) == typeof(b.key1)){
    alert('absent in both!');
}
```

See [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SpXDm/).

If you want a property to be undefined, remove it, for example in PHP use [`unset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) before `json_encode`:

```
$a = array('key1' => null, 'key2' => 'value2');
unset($a['key1']);
json_encode($a); // {"key2":"value2"}
```

<sup>1</sup> You can use a [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

Comment: Ah, I should have searched for the spec when my initial search came up empty, that's a good call. Thanks for the tips, though I think for my purpose I will have to return false then each through the object and set the falses to undefined; its sort of a misuse of undefined since the variable needs to be present, just with no value.